# Services menu polluted by apps from another installation

Tags: macos, services

Reinstalled 10.15, signed into icloud, had previous 10.13 on another partition for a while.

10.15 is a clean install. The apps that provide those services haven't even been installed.
[image]

`~/Library/Services` is empty. Tried grepping the whole filesystem for those. No match.

The only place they seem to exist is in `defaults` manager. So I tried removing 
`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.ServicesMenu.Services.plist` and `~/Library/Preferences/pbs.plist`. Didn't help.

Why are those services in that menu on a clean installation and how to I get rid of them?

Comment: Can you right click and remove ?

Comment: best you ever get is 'show in Finder' - which invariably goes to the Applications folder not the Service location

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'll be damned.

[image]

In the evening I removed 10.13 partition. Immediately after the list remained the same. In the morning the list was fixed.

I believe what happened is, this list is constructed by scanning all available mountpoints. it went into the old volume and picked up the old service files. It probably runs an update every few hours.

This is such a weird behavior.

Comment: Some Library components, like Services, QuickLook and Spotlight plug-ins, exist inside the Application's bundle, and are picked up by the OS. If the app is available, then the Services will appear.